# Передача параметров с FORM action используя POST

Tags: action, post, html, form, perl

вот есть форма, но она не передает переменные "value1&param2=value2"

```
<form action="http://exmple.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2" method="POST">
```

Вернее в бараузере оно присутсвует, но данные скриптом не восприняты, и только если нажать в браузерной строке энтер, скрипт подгрузится с учетом этих переменных.

Поменять метод на GET нельзя.

Скрипт написан на PERL

Объясните, если должно работать, то почему не работает.
Eсли не должно, то со сеноской на авторитетный ресурс.

Бьюсь целый день, как в яндексе так и в гугле искал и очень-очень долго...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

глянь [тут](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/web-development/2130664) решение есть - и вроде PERL принимает только либо POST либо GET - то что в method прописано

Comment: спасибо, я так и думал что оба принимать - это от лукавого ;)

Comment: хотя PHP такое воспринимает